# Is there a way to implement condition/search on metadata(json) stored as a string in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, search, metadata

i want to fetch results according to columns stored in metadata column...where json data is stored as string

criteria:- fetch price from metadata from  column name stored in type. type can have fixedPrice,timedAuction, unlimitedAuction

i am using npm module- mysql@2.18.1
phpmyadmin - Server version: 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
[image]

I want to implement this in sql query itself

meta data after parsing:-

```
  "metadata": {
    "file": "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmctyySWTJtLGDjCQkDd7N9DjhpY9ffvmPZ8JiYm1Y9t1a",
    "putOnMarketplace": true,
    "fixedPrice": {
      "price": 0.1,
      "currency": "",
      "name": "Tester colectibles 2",
      "description": "scs",
      "royalties": "10",
      "multipleCopies": "",
      "invitationCode": "959671"
    },
    "timedAuction": {
      "price": "",
      "expirationDate": {
        "id": 1,
        "value": "1 Day"
      },
      "name": "",
      "description": "",
      "royalties": "",
      "invitationCode": ""
    },
    "unlimitedAuction": {
      "price": "",
      "name": "",
      "description": "",
      "royalties": "",
      "invitationCode": ""
    },
    "mediaType": "image",
    "type": "fixedPrice",
    "tokenType": "erc721"
  }
```

Comment: Of course this is possible. The complexity of the solution depends on precise MySQL version, JSON structure variability and needed selection criteria.

Comment: *meta data after parsing* Do not parse - the result of your "parsing" is not valid JSON. Provide real sample data - and not as a picture but as online fiddle or textual code-formatted CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (3-5 rows enough).